# How to print transparent images in Win32 (color key)

Tags: winapi, printing, transparency, alphablending

I am **trying to print a transparent image** in a Win32 application. The image has an alpha channel, but I could also live with a simple transparency mask.

When using the [::AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method it is shown correctly on screen and gets printed correctly on my HP ColorSphere printer. However, with PDF printers (e.g. Primo PDF) the image appears opaque in the PDF.

When insertig the same image in Word, setting the transparency color to white, the image appears correctly transparent when using Primo PDF.

**How should I draw my image so that the transparency also works in PDF printers? Or: how is Microsoft Word achieving this?**

Thanks,

Fabian

Comment: It's very difficult.  Excellent article here: http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/transparency

Comment: Are you testing the device using GetDeviceCaps with SHADEBLENDCAPS? Also this looks interesting: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html.

Comment: Thanks for the article. @Ironside: GetDeviceCaps returns true for SHADEBLENDCAPS in both cases.